# How to use javascript executor for webdriver sampler in Jmeter

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I need to use below javascript executor lines for webdriver sampler in Jmeter.

WebElement el1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/button/span[contains( text(),'View Report')]"));
             JavascriptExecutor executor1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
             executor1.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el1);

I tried to use below lines but getting below error message in logs
var btnView = pkg.By.xpath("//div/button/span[contains( text(),'View Report')]");
WDS.browser.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath(arguments[0]).click();", btnView )
Error message:
ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: Argument is of an illegal type: org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath

Is there any way use javascript executor in Webdriver Sampler?

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format your code as code and format the error message. See the help on formatting if you are unsure on how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't need this cast to JavascriptExecutor
2. You don't need this `arguments[0].click();` in the JavaScript will be quite enough, there is no need to re-locate the element, moreover `document.getElementByXpath` is not something supported currently by the [document object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp)

So amend your code as follows:

```
var btnView = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//div/button/span[contains( text(),'View Report')]"))
WDS.browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", btnView)
```

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for more WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks.

Comment: This doesn't work with the Java implementation of the WebDriver sampler (not the Javascript). Errors out with the message "executeScript( java.lang.String, java.lang.String ) not found in class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver" Not sure why WebDriver plugin is trying to map executeScript method to ChromeDriver, not to org.openqa.selenium.Javascriptexecutor class.

Comment: is there any solution for this? i am getting the same error as mentioned by @GordonFreaman while implementing using java

Comment: When you choose `Java` in the "Script Language" dropdown it is not a real Java, it is [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) interpreter which has slightly different syntax and some performance constraints. I would recommend switching to `Groovy` language - it is more Java compliant and has some nice features on top of it, check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details